# They show me the error 'All arrays must be of the same length'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I try many method but they will not solve they show me the error:

> All arrays must be of the same length

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests
import pandas as pd

review = []
ratings = []
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
}
for page in range(1, 5):
    r = requests.get(
        "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=redmi&page=2&qid=1631528810&ref=sr_pg_={page}".format(
            page=page
        ),
        headers=headers,
    )
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    for d in soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "s-result-item"}):
        rating = d.find("span", attrs={"class": "a-icon-alt"})
        if rating is not None:
            ratings.append(rating.text)

        reviews = d.find("span", class_="a-size-base")
        if reviews is not None:
            review.append(reviews.text)


df = pd.DataFrame({"rating": ratings, "reviews": review})
df.to_csv("products .csv", index=False, encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: I would imagine your `ratings` and `reviews` aren't the same length, then. You'd need to fix your scraping code to take that into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ratings` and `reviews` aren't the same length and you were scraping wrong containers. I made the necessary modifications, now it should work:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests
import pandas as pd

review = []
ratings = []
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
}
for page in range(1, 5):
    cookies = {'session': '17ab96bd8ffbe8ca58a78657a918558'}
    r = requests.get(
        "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=redmi&page=2&qid=1631528810&ref=sr_pg_={page}".format(
            page=page
        ),
        headers=headers,
        cookies =cookies
    )
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    for d in soup.select(".s-result-item[data-component-type='s-search-result']"):
        rating = d.find("span", attrs={"class": "a-icon-alt"})
        if rating is not None:
            ratings.append(rating.text)
        else:
            ratings.append("-")

        reviews = d.find("span", class_="a-size-base")
        if reviews is not None and rating is not None:
            review.append(reviews.text)
        else:
            review.append("-")


df = pd.DataFrame({"rating": ratings, "reviews": review})
df.to_csv("products.csv", index=False, encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: they gave me an empty csv file now

Comment: It's because Amazon blocks you while sending requests consecutively. You can work around this issue by giving a ```cookie``` to the ```request.get()``` method. I updated the code accordingly, please have a try.